# Cloud spanner and doctrine 2.x

Tags: doctrine-orm, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Is there already an implementation for doctrine2 with cloud spanner? Or can this be achieved with the PDOMySQL driver class?

Comment: It is not available in Cloud Spanner at this moment. feel free to open a Feature Request in https://issuetracker.google.com/ so it can be tracked and other users can follow the updates. Let us know when you have done it please :-)

Comment: Thanks, I've created a issue. [Doctrine 2 support for Cloud Spanner PHP client library](https://issuetracker.google.com/111146574)

Comment: Thanks a lot for letting us know.

Comment: @victor-herasme-perez Would you mind making your comment as an ansewer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Done. I hope it has been helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not available in [Cloud Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/) at this moment. Feel free to open a Feature Request in https://issuetracker.google.com/ so it can be tracked and other users can follow the updates.